How to handle different response types using openapi-generator-cli generated Rust client
I made this nestjs/swagger endpoint which may return different type Data Transfer Objects (DTO).
    @Post('/quiz')
    @ApiOkResponse({  description: "Status of users collection achievements", type: PrizeDto})
    @ApiAcceptedResponse({description: "Prize awarded", type: GiftCardDto})
    @ApiCreatedResponse({description: "Prize awarded", type: VoucherDto})
    @ApiNoContentResponse({description: "No prize available"})
    @ApiBadRequestResponse({description: "Don't ask me that"})
    @ApiForbiddenResponse({description: "You shall not pass"})
    makeSubmission(@Body() submission: QuizSubmissionDto) : Promise<PrizeDto | GiftCardDto | VoucherDto | undefined> {
        return undefined;
    }

After I generate Rust code using openapi-generator-cli, I get generated code that just does not handle any other 2xx range responses than 200.
/// struct for typed errors of method [`report_controller_make_submission`]
#[derive(Debug, Clone, Serialize, Deserialize)]
#[serde(untagged)]
pub enum ReportControllerMakeSubmissionError {
    Status400(),
    Status403(),
    UnknownValue(serde_json::Value),
}

pub async fn report_controller_make_submission(configuration: &configuration::Configuration, quiz_submission_dto: models::QuizSubmissionDto) -> Result<models::PrizeDto, Error<ReportControllerMakeSubmissionError>> {
    let local_var_configuration = configuration;

    let local_var_client = &local_var_configuration.client;

    let local_var_uri_str = format!("{}/quiz", local_var_configuration.base_path);
    let mut local_var_req_builder = local_var_client.request(reqwest::Method::POST, local_var_uri_str.as_str());

    if let Some(ref local_var_user_agent) = local_var_configuration.user_agent {
        local_var_req_builder = local_var_req_builder.header(reqwest::header::USER_AGENT, local_var_user_agent.clone());
    }
    local_var_req_builder = local_var_req_builder.json(&quiz_submission_dto);

    let local_var_req = local_var_req_builder.build()?;
    let local_var_resp = local_var_client.execute(local_var_req).await?;

    let local_var_status = local_var_resp.status();
    let local_var_content = local_var_resp.text().await?;

    if !local_var_status.is_client_error() && !local_var_status.is_server_error() {
        serde_json::from_str(&local_var_content).map_err(Error::from)
    } else {
        let local_var_entity: Option<ReportControllerMakeSubmissionError> = serde_json::from_str(&local_var_content).ok();
        let local_var_error = ResponseContent { status: local_var_status, content: local_var_content, entity: local_var_entity };
        Err(Error::ResponseError(local_var_error))
    }
}

If that generated Rust code tries to process for example 204 NO CONTENT response fails at JSON parsing and error from serde_json::from_str doesn't even have http response code.
I have tried and experienced this same issue with nestjs / swagger and also using AWS API Gateway with models.
What is the correct way to handle different 2xx range responses that do not return same data type with Rust client generated from OpenAPI document?
